# How to sort a .txt file numerically

Tags: python, sorting

I am having trouble sorting my .txt file by a numerical value. I have attached the code and am trying to get it to sort by score,
I also cant get it to print each new score to a new line from the txt file.

```
def Highscore():
    name = input("What is your name for the scoreboard?")
    newhighscore =(name, highscore)
    newline = ("\n")
    HighscoreWrite = open ("highscore.txt", "a")
    HighscoreWrite.write(highscore )
    HighscoreWrite.write(name )
    HighscoreWrite.write("\n")
    HighscoreWrite.close()
    HighscoreRead = open("highscore.txt", "r" )
    ordered = sorted(HighscoreRead)


    print (ordered)    



    print (HighscoreRead.read())
    #print (newhighscore)
    HighscoreRead.close()
retry = "Yes"
while retry == "Yes":
    print ("Welcome to this quiz.\n")
    score = 0
    attempt = 0
    while score < 10:
        correct = Question()
        if correct:
            score += 1
            attempt += 1
            print ("Well done, You got it right")
        else:
            print ("Good try but maybe next time")
            attempt += 1
    highscore = score, ("/") ,attempt
    highscore = str(highscore)
    message = print ("You scored", (score), "out of ",(attempt))
    Highscore();
    retry = input("Would you like to try again? Yes/No")
```

Comment: read all data, convert text to int and then sort it. Or use `key=` parameter in `sorted()`

Answer (score 1):

In order to sort a file numerically, you must create a `key(line)` function that takes a line as parameter and returns the numeric value of the score.

Assuming that highscore.txt is a text file where each line starts with a numerical value followed with a space, the `key` function could be:

```
def key_func(line):
    return int(line.lstrip().split(' ')[0])
```

You can then use `ordered = sorted(HighscoreRead, key = key_func)`

As it is a one line function, you can also use a lambda:

```
ordered = sorted(HighscoreRead, key= (lambda line: int(line.lstrip().split(' ')[0])))
```

Comment: For clarity and python 2 compatibility the key should be specified as a keyword argument. Also the extra parentheses around the lambda make it more confusing - case in point: you missed one at the end.